# [__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds for empty array'

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsarray

My application runs fine on Simulater 6.1 but it crashes on 7.0.

Here is the crash log:

```
[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x024595e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x021dc8b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x023fa556 -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 246
    3   OHUM                                0x0003c9b7 -[PatientSelectionViewCon tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 503
    4   UIKit                               0x00cdcd2f -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 412
    5   UIKit                               0x00cdce03 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:] + 69
    6   UIKit                               0x00cc103c -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 2146
    7   UIKit                               0x00cbf531 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsImmediatelyIfNecessary] + 66
    8   UIKit                               0x00ccd26f -[UITableView _visibleCells] + 35
    9   UIKit                               0x00ccd2c4 -[UITableView visibleCells] + 33
    10  UIKit                               0x00cc65c2 -[UITableView _updateAnimationDidStop:finished:context:] + 1484
    11  UIKit                               0x00cc5da9 __46-[UITableView _updateWithItems:updateSupport:]_block_invoke762 + 90
    12  UIKit                               0x00c50b75 -[UIViewAnimationBlockDelegate _didEndBlockAnimation:finished:context:] + 306
    13  UIKit                               0x00c3a81c -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 267
    14  UIKit                               0x00c3ab04 -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 80
    15  QuartzCore                          0x00a41e84 _ZN2CA5Layer23run_animation_callbacksEPv + 304
    16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x027f14b0 _dispatch_client_callout + 14
    17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x027df766 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 340
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x024bea5e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 14
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x023ff72b __CFRunLoopRun + 1963
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x023feb33 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x023fe94b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    22  GraphicsServices                    0x044949d7 GSEventRunModal + 192
    23  GraphicsServices                    0x044947fe GSEventRun + 104
    24  UIKit                               0x00bee94b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    25  OHUM                                0x00021fed main + 141
    26  libdyld.dylib                       0x02a81725 start + 0
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

The method is:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    PatientListCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    cell.delegate = self;

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    if(indexPath.row == selectedIndex.row){

        //Hide all previous dropdown items.
        [self removePreviousDropDownItems];

        cell.isExpanded = YES;


    }
    else {

        cell.isExpanded = NO;

    }
     // I check the Array here
     if([self.objPatientSelectionVO.arrPatientVO count]==0)
    {
        return cell;
    }

    PatientVO * objVO = [self.objPatientSelectionVO.arrPatientVO objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [cell setupData:objVO];

    cell.tag = indexPath.row;


    //Sets the size of the drop down depending on the expanded state of the Cell.
    [cell handleExpansion];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Please post your cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: @Kuldeep Rajput: You need to do some basic debugging.  Right before doing objectAtIndex, NSLog the count of the self.objPatientSelectionVO.arrPatientVO array and the indexPath.row.  At some point, the indexPath.row must be exceeding (count-1).  Then do NSLogging and debugging of where the array is populated or set.  Keep backtracking until you reach the point where the behavior is different in iOS 7 vs iOS 6.  Simply put: Do some debugging (NSLogs, step through the code that sets the array, etc).

Comment: Hey Hi Anna i fixed that issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    PatientListCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    cell.delegate = self;

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    if(indexPath.row == selectedIndex.row){

        //Hide all previous dropdown items.
        [self removePreviousDropDownItems];

        cell.isExpanded = YES;


    }
    else {

        cell.isExpanded = NO;

    }
    //This check for Array is empty then return cell
    if([self.objPatientSelectionVO.arrPatientVO count]==0)
    {
        return cell;
    }


    PatientVO * objVO = [self.objPatientSelectionVO.arrPatientVO objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [cell setupData:objVO];

    cell.tag = indexPath.row;


    //Sets the size of the drop down depending on the expanded state of the Cell.
    [cell handleExpansion];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This array is empty
`self.objPatientSelectionVO.arrPatientVO`

if this is your main array that you fill the data with ... then you need to return the count of the array in numberOfRows method

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.objPatientSelectionVO.arrPatientVO
```

is empty. Make sure that you added your objects before you make your tableView. You are out indexing from your array

and:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
   return self.objPatientSelectionVO.arrPatientVO.count;
}
```

Comment: Thanx but still app is crash this app is run fine on ios 6 ipad but when same build i am trying to run on ios7 device that time it crashed is there Any API Issue or some thing else